# How to check the TextView inside card extends the cardView size in recyclerView with Horizontal scrolling?

Tags: java, android, xml, textview, cardview

I am creating one reader in My Application where I used **Cardview** to show each page context using **Textview**. There is a single Textview inside each **cardView**.

Here, I am using Horizontal scroll having CardView height as **"wrap_content"**.

## Problem

So, now the problem is the page content in each page is dynamic. While I am showing **TextView** content- when the content is too large, some lines got cut off at bottom like below image-

[image]

which I want to show in the next card where no line get cut off like below-

[image]

Here is the code given below of each layout items-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/card_view_left"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
                card_view:contentPadding="10dp"
                card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorTransparent"
                card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
                card_view:cardMaxElevation="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-7dp"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvPageNo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:text=""
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:visibility="gone"

                    />

                <com.actinarium.aligned.TextView
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/tv_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
                    android:textSize="14sp"

                    app:leading="16sp"
                    app:firstLineLeading="24sp"

                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"

                    />


                </LinearLayout>


            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/viewPageUnderLine"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="#c0c0c0"

            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            />

    </LinearLayout>


    <com.wang.avi.AVLoadingIndicatorView
        android:id="@+id/loading_indicator"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:indicatorName="LineScaleIndicator"
        app:indicatorColor="@color/colorOrange"

        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: do you want text in textview in few defined lines like 2 3 and then on clicking that particular card, detail will be shown next. right ?

Comment: No I want to cover the entire screen to show the textview inside cardview without cutting any line.

Comment: could you please upload images what do you required or not for better understanding of problem

Comment: The question has been edited, please check @faiizii

Comment: sorry but your xml code doesn't look like the screen shots. i think

Comment: Sorry, I can't show the exact screen shot as the xml layout. But the picture I uploaded was to clear the problem what is exactly same what I mentioned..

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to set android:maxLines="10" and android:minLines="10". The parent cardview should then has height matching the textview. 
If any text shall be truncated, then take the truncated text and place in the next cardview which also follows the above rules.

Comment: And how should I work with the truncated text like you mentioned " take the truncated text and place in the next cardview" ?